# How to convert POJO object to json string using gson for a specified field?

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit2 for password recovery, an API request is sent to the server  with an email address which is entered by the user.
I'm only setting the email in the POJO ,and after the conversion, the JSON string looks like this:

```
{"email":"email@email.com", "password":"", "password_confirmation":"", "token":""}
```

But the JSON I need to send out, should look like this:

```
{"email":"email@email.com"}
```

If I'll create another POJO class with an email param then I'll get the required string, but I just want to know if it is possible, using the current POJO.

How would one convert a POJO object to a JSON string using gson for a specified field?

Please Refer to the below code:

```
   public class User {

    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String password_confirmation;
    private String token;

    public User() {
       this.email="";
       this.password="";
       this.password_confirmation="";
       this.token="";
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPassword_confirmation() {
        return password_confirmation;
    }

    public void setPassword_confirmation(String password_confirmation) {
        this.password_confirmation = password_confirmation;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }
}
```

My Api interface

```
public interface Api{

  @POST("/api/password/create")
  @Headers({"Accept:application/json", "Content-Type:application/json"})
  Call<User> Create(@Body RequestBody requestBody); 

}
```

My Retrofit method

```
 private void authenticateEmail(final Context context) {

        User user=new User();
        Api api=new Api();

        String email = edt_forgot_email.getText().toString().trim();

       Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setDateFormat(SERVICE_DATE_FORMAT)
                    .setLenient()
                    .create();
        api = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();

        user.setEmail(email);
        Gson lGson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat(SERVICE_DATE_FORMAT).create();
        String jsonString =  lGson.toJson(user);
        Log.d("debug", "jsonString==>" + jsonString);


        final RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), jsonString);
        Call<User> call = api.Create(requestBody);
        Log.d("debug", "url: " + call.request().url().toString());

        call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<User> call, @NonNull Response<User> response) {
                Log.d("debug", "responsecode==>" + response.code());
                Log.d("debug", "responsebody==>" + response.body());

                if (response.code() == 200) {

                   String msg = "We have emailed you OTP";
                  Toast.makeText(activity, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } 
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<User> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

               Toast.makeText(activity, "server error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this code from constructor :

```
public User() {
    this.email="";
    this.password="";
    this.password_confirmation="";
    this.token="";
}
```

If you want to exclude empty values from output json, you should make it as null.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Keeping empty constructor solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a JSON Object for the single field like this:

```
JSONObject data =new JSONObject();
data.put("email", email@email.com)
```

send data object to the retrofit.